# Wohin gehört das "ist"?

Tags: sentence-structure

Heißt es
"Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes Haus, sind beide schön"
oder
"Da A ein rotes Haus und B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Variante 1

> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes Haus, sind beide schön.

**Aufbau des Hauptsatzes**
Das finite Verb des Hauptsatzes ist das Kopula-Verb »sind«. Das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes ist das Indefinitpronomen »beide«, das hier in seiner Pluralform verwendet wird (der Singular wäre »beides«). Subjekt und Verb stimmen daher in ihrer grammatikalischen Zahl (Singular oder Plural) überein, so wie es sein soll. Das Adjektiv »schön« wird hier prädikativ verwendet und ist als Prädikatsnomen über das Kopulaverb »sind« an das Subjekt gebunden, beschreibt also eine Eigenschaft des Subjekts.

**Rolle des Teils vor dem Komma**
Damit wäre der Hauptsatz eigentlich komplett. Aber in jedem korrekten deutschen Satz, der ein ganz normaler Aussagesatz ist, steht das Verb (hier: »sein«) immer an Position 2. Daher muss alles, was davor steht, die Position 1 belegen, und das ist der ganze Nebensatz »Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes Haus«. Dieser Satz ist aus Sicht des Hauptsatzes so etwas wie eine adverbielle Ergänzung. Weil diese Ergänzung selbst ein ganzer Satz ist, nennt man das einen Adverbialsatz. Dieser Adverbialsatz liefert eine Begründung für die Aussage des Hauptsatzes, ist also ein Kausalsatz.

**Aufbau eines einfachen Kausalsatzes**
Kausalsätze werden mit den Konjunktionen »weil« oder »da« eingeleitet und sind Nebensätze. Für untergeordnete Nebensätze gilt die Regel, dass das finite Verb immer ganz am Ende des Nebensatzes stehen muss:

> Weil Simon den ganzen Tag mit seinen Schulfreunden Martin und Lukas in Garten von Martins Eltern Fußball **spielt,** wird er abends müde sein.

<sub>(Nebensätze können untergeordnet oder nebengeordnet sein. Die soeben beschriebe Position für das finite Verb gilt nur bei untergeordneten Nebensätzen. Bei nebengeordneten Nebensätzen gilt dieselbe Position-2-Regel wie bei Hauptsätzen: *»Simon wird abends müde sein, denn er **spielt** mit seinen Freunden Fußball.«*)</sub>

Die »rohen« Kausalsätze, die in deinem Beispiel verborgen sind, sind diese beiden:

> Da A ein rotes Haus ist, ...
> Da B ein grünes Haus ist, ...

**Satzverbindung mit *und***
Man kann zwei Hauptsätze mit der Konjunktion und verbinden:

> Claudia schläft. Paul trinkt Wasser.
> Claudia schläft und Paul trinkt Wasser.

Dasselbe kann man aber auch mit gleichartigen Nebensätzen machen. Wenn man die beiden Kausalsätze aus dem angefragten Beispiel auf diese Weise verbindet, und sie in den Hauptsatz einbettet, erhält man das:

> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und da B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.

Es gibt also zwei Begründungen, die in zwei separaten Kausalsätzen formuliert sind, die durch die Konjunktion »und« miteinander verbunden sind.

**Koordinationsellipse**
Es fällt auf, dass die beiden Kausalsätze mit derselben Konjunktion (»da«) beginnen und dasselbe finite Verb (»ist«) verwenden. Diese Wiederholungen liefern keine neue Information und können vom Empfänger der Nachricht leicht rekonstruiert werden. Aus diesen sprachökonomischen Gründen hat sich schon vor Jahrtausenden eine Technik entwickelt, die heute »Koordinationsellipse« genannt wird. Man lässt wiederholte Satzbestandteile einfach weg:

> 1. Ludwig isst die Pizza. Sabine isst den Salat.
> 2. Ludwig isst die Pizza und Sabine isst den Salat.
> 3. Ludwig isst die Pizza und Sabine den Salat.

In Zeile 1 stehen zwei getrennte Hauptsätze, die in Zeile 2 durch die Konjunktion »und« zu einem Satz verbunden werden, in dem nun zweimal dasselbe Verb steht. In Zeile 3 liegt eine Koordinationsellipse vor, die dadurch erzeugt wird, dass man die zweite Instanz des doppelten Verbs weglässt. Und das funktioniert genauso auch bei Nebensätzen:

- Ausgangssituation:

  > Da A ein rotes Haus ist und da B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.
- Koordinationsellipse um die doppelte Konjunktion »da« und das doppelte Verb »ist« wegzulassen:

  > Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes Haus, sind beide schön.

Aber da ist noch ein Wort doppelt: Das Subjekt »Haus« der beiden ursprünglichen Kausalsätze.

- Koordinationsellipse um nun auch das doppelte Subjekt »Haus« wegzulassen:

  > Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes, sind beide schön.

Deutsche Muttersprachler ziehen meist jene Form vor, in der alle Verdoppelungen weggelassen werden. Wenn jedoch betont werden soll, dass B ebenfalls ein Haus ist, spricht nichts dagegen, das zweite Subjekt trotzdem zu verwenden.

---

### Variante 2

> Da A ein rotes Haus und B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.

Auch das ist eine grammatisch korrekte Form einer Koordinationsellipse. Diesmal wurde aber die erste Instanz des Verbs weggelassen. Die erste Instanz wegzulassen wäre im Fall der Konjunktion »da« nicht erlaubt, weil sonst der erste Kausalsatz keine vorangestellte Konjunktion hätte. Bei dem Verb und auch beim Subjekt darf aber auch die erste Instanz weggelassen werden, dann muss eben die letzte Instanz vorhanden sein.

Die übliche Vorgehensweise, bei der die erste Instanz stehen bleibt, nennt man »Rechtstilgung«. Wenn die erste entfernt wird, und nur die letzte vorhanden bleibt, nennt man das eine »Linkstilgung«.

Wenn auch vom doppelten »Haus« nur eine Instanz im Satz verbleiben soll, sollten entweder nur Rechtstilgungen oder nur Linkstilgungen durchgeführt werden.

- zwei Rechtstilgungen

  > Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes, sind beide schön.
- zwei Linksstilgungen

  > Da A ein rotes und B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.

---

### Was ist besser?

Grundsätzlich gilt, dass Rechtstilgungen leichter verständlich sind, und dass ihnen daher im Zweifelsfall der Vorzug zu geben ist. Im Fall einer Linkstilgung fehlt am Beginn des Satz ein Wort, das erst später im Satz auftaucht und dann im Kopf des Empfängers an die bereits vergangene Stelle des Satzes eingesetzt werden muss. Bei einer Rechtstilgung sind die bereits gelesenen oder gehörten Wörter schon im Kopf des Empfängers vorhanden, und können leichter eingefügt werden, wenn die Stelle verarbeitet wird, an der sie ausgelassen wurden.

Answer (score 3):

### Kurze Antwort

Geschmackssache

### Ausführliche Antwort

Diese Frage läßt sich fast mathematisch (mit einem "unmathematischen Twist" am Ende) beantworten:

Der Nebensatz "Da A ein rotes Haus ist" muss im Deutschen Verbletztstellung haben, daher das *ist* nach dem ersten Haus. Die mit einer Konjunktion angehängte Nebensatzergänzung muss dass Verb aus dem gleichen Grund ebenfalls am Schluss haben. Der vollständige Satz hieße dann

> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und da B ein grünes Haus ist,....

Jetzt ist das natürlich doppelt gemoppelt und hört sich holprig an. Daher darf man (als Ellipse) eins der "ist" (und, im übrigen, auch eins der Häuser) weglassen und die Nebensätze zusammenziehen. Welches der Prädikate (und Häuser) der Ellipse zum Opfer fällt und weggelassen wird, ist pure Geschmackssache (das ist der "unmathematische Twist"), daher sind sowohl

> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes,

als auch

> Da A ein rotes und B ein grünes Haus ist,

(und auch Varianten, bei denen das "Haus" nicht im Teil endet, der das Verb trägt oder auch gar nicht weggelasen wird wie in deinem Beispiel) vollkommen richtig und im Prinzip bedeutungsgleich.

Aus stilistischen Gründen sollte man die Klammer, die zwischen Subjekt und Prädikat aufgeht, nicht zu lange werden lassen. In deinem Beispiel ist das jetzt nicht der Fall. Ist aber der zweite Nebensatzteil wesentlich länger, so dass das "ist" an das Ende eines Bandwurms geraten würde wie in

> Da A ein rotes Haus und B ein grünes, das in einem schönen Garten steht, ist,

hat man einfach zu viele Satzkomponenten zu lange "in der Luft hängen", so dass der Satz schwer verständlich wird (Aber im Prinzip immer noch grammatikalisch richtig ist).

Daher gibt es gewisse Vorteile, wenn das Prädikat im ersten Teil steht und die Klammer frühzeitig geschlossen wird.

Answer (score 1):

First things first: both of your variants are correct.

The main sentence here is:

<...> sind beide schön.

Before that are two *Finalsätze*, both starting with "da",  ending with "ist" and coupled by "und":

> Da ... ist und da ... ist, (main sentence).

You are probably asking by now what I am talking about, because the second "da" and the second "ist" are not there. This is correct, but they are - virtually - still there. This is a device called "ellipsis". (I was tortured 4 years with having to learn ancient greek, so, to make up for it, I now can show off by telling you that "ellipsis" means "omission".)

This device is mainly used in colloquial language, for instance:

> Q: What time is it?
> A: Seven!

The correct answer would be "it is seven o'clock" but all the obvious parts, "it is" and "o'clock", are left out.

See more about this in an [answer I wrote](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/74194/50622) for a similar question.

It is possible to omit the second "da" and either "ist", the following variants are all correct. The first "da" needs to stay in place. You can even omit "Haus", which is the same in both reasonings too. You *don't have to* omit anything, it just sounds a little more eloquent (because breaking up the repetitive pattern) if you do - which doesn't change the correctness at all.

> Da A ein rotes und B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.
> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes, sind beide schön.
> Da A ein rotes Haus ist und B ein grünes Haus ist, sind beide schön.

If you omit everything possible, like in the first variation, the sentence structure changes and the two *Finalsätze* become one. Since they are coupled with "und" anyway this grammatical difference doesn't take away from the correctness.

Comment: Warum antwortest du in einer Fremdsprache, von der du nicht wissen kannst, ob sie der/die Fragensteller*in beherrscht? Siehe https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/a/837/1487